# Bayes' rule and change of measure

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

I wonder about how to explain best why the following formula (1) is called "Bayes' formula".

Given a probability space $(\Omega,\mathfrak A,P)$, a sub-$\sigma$-algebra $\mathfrak B\subset \mathfrak A$, a strictly positive random variable $Z\in L^1(\mathbb P)$ with $E[Z] =1$, we can define the equivalent probability measure $Q$ via $Q(A) = E[Z \textbf 1_A]$. Then, for any $Y\in L^1(\Omega,\mathfrak A,Q)$, we have
\begin{equation}
(1) \qquad E^Q[Y \mid \mathfrak B] = \frac{E[YZ\mid \mathfrak B]}{E[Z \mid \mathfrak B]}.
\end{equation}
Note that, if $A \in \mathfrak A$ with $P(A) > 0$, then we can put $Z = \textbf 1_A / P(A)$ in order to get $Q = P(\cdot\mid A)$.

But what is the precise relation to the elementary formula due to Bayes/Laplace, i.e. for $A,B \in \mathfrak A$ with $P(A)P(B) >0$ we have
\begin{equation*}
P(B\mid A) =  \frac{P(B)P(A\mid B)}{P(A)},
\end{equation*}
how do we have to choose $\mathfrak A, \mathfrak B, Z,Y$ above in order to derive this formula (without using the elementary argument which shows the elementary rule)?

Otherwise, there would – in my humble opinion – be no reason to call it "Bayes' formula".

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathfrak B$ be trivial, and set $Y = 1_B$, $Z = 1_A / P(A)$. Then:

$$
P(B \mid A) = E^Q[Y \mid \mathfrak B] = \frac{E[YZ \mid \mathfrak B]}{E[Z \mid \mathfrak B]} = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A)},$$

which isn't exactly Bayes' rule, but it's pretty close; you can of course derive Bayes' rule by applying this result twice.